# Java Annox library relocated

Tags: java, binding, xjc

I’m trying to use the Annox library, but it seems that java.net has been shut down. I would like to know where the library was relocated to.

I always receive the following error message: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unsupported binding namespace http://annox.dev.java.net". Perhaps you meant "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc?

I'm trying to modify jaxb bindings.

---

(*Annox* is an open source project for reading arbitrary Java annotations from XML resources.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annox is still alive. You can find the original repository [here](https://github.com/highsource/annox)

We took the repository and merged it into the maven-jaxb2-plugin of highsource to make [jaxb-tools](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools) (which also contains the annotate plugin and the jaxb2-basics plugins, all related to `org.jvnet.jaxb` groupId)

You can find the [migration guide](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB-Tools-Migration-Guide) on how to go from initial artifacts to newest one (v2 for jaxb2, v3 for jaxb3 and v4 for jaxb4).

You can also find the revived documentation in [annox wiki](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/Annox-Home) on how it works and how to use it (taken back from offline confluence).

Feel free to open issue in jaxb-tools if needed